# Closure Compiler - can a method be public ONLY for testing?

Tags: testing, google-closure-compiler

I have a method that I need to test, but ultimately I don't want this method to be public. Is there a tag I can use so that I can use the method in my tests (as if it were public) but the method will be private in the final result?

Comment: What do you mean by "public" and "private"? Are you referencing annotations, code scope or something else?

Comment: I mean public and private in the sense of annotating a class method as '@private' or '@export'. I need the method to be @private in reality, but to test it properly it would be useful to be able to access the method name directly in my test file. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to define a compiler @define value, that you set either for test code or unset otherwise:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var TESTING = false;
```

then you can do something like this:

```
if (TESTING) {
  var someMethodVisibleForTesting = function() {}
}
```

This is about your only option.

Comment: Thanks, this could work. I'd rather not have any special testing values floating around in the compiled code, but I'll see what the team here thinks about this as a solution.

Comment: If you are using the ADVANCED compilation, the code will be removed completely when TESTING = false